# I'm not able to bind time correctly in table

Tags: angularjs

I tried by placing lot of directives to display correct time in table.But I couldn't make this done.I'm sharing the fiddle here.The time in table is 5:30 min more than what I have given.Please help me to solve this.
[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k52pmowv/)

```
Thanks
```

Comment: try using Moment.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is the timezone, You need to convert using a filter to local timezone,

You could check this by adding like this,

```
<td>{{row.description  | UTCToNow  }}</td>
```

**Filter:**

```
myapp.filter('UTCToNow', ['moment', function (moment) {
     return function (input, format) {
           return  moment.utc(input).format('LLL');        

         }
    }]
);
```

[`JSFiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/k52pmowv/47/)

Comment: Filter is not working sajeetharan. i want to display in table like this (Oct 29, 2010 9:10:23 AM)